# How to get changed value using array_diff in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function changeData(Request $request)
{
     $product = Product::where('_id', '=', $request->product['_id'])->first()->toArray();

        //result product : 
        // array(4) {
        //     ["_id"]=>
        //     string(24) "5fffc00df116005c724859f2"
        //     ["name"]=>
        //     string(6) "iphone"
        //     ["slug"]=>
        //     string(14) "product-iphone"
        //     ["status"]=>
        //     string(14) "1"
        // }


        // result $request->product :
        // array(4) {
        //     ["_id"]=>
        //     string(24) "5fffc00df116005c724859f2"
        //     ["name"]=>
        //     string(7) "samsung"
        //     ["slug"]=>
        //     string(15) "product-samsung"
        //     ["status"]=>
        //     string(14) "1"
        // }

        $diff = array_diff($request->product, $product);
        var_dump($diff);
}
```

**ERROR:** *'Array to string conversion'*

*If I use the :*

```
$diff = array_diff(array_map('serialize',$request->product), array_map('serialize',$product));
```

Then it will return the following result:

```
 array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(15) "s:6:"samsung";"
        ["slug"]=>
        string(25) "s:15:"product-samsung";"
      }
```

The results above are correct for what I need. But it shows `"s:6:` and `"s:15:` inside the result. Is there a way for these two to not appear. I just want to get the correct result eg `name` is `samsung`. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to check which fields were updated?

Comment: @mohammadmahdibaleghsefat Yes, i want that

Comment: are u sure that both $request->product and $product are array ? maybe one of them is object ? specially $request->product . use $diff = array_diff(((array)$request->product), ((array)$product )); and check for error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$diff = array_diff(array_map('serialize', $request->product), array_map('serialize', $product));

$multidimensional_diff = array_map('unserialize', $diff);

print_r($multidimensional_diff);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting.Thank you for your help with my work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which fields were updated, you can use `isDirsty` method. For example, you want to check if the user has changed the email, send an email verification:

```
if ($user->isDirty('email'))
{
    // Do something
}
```

[Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes)

Comment: If you use this method, for example, if there are 10 fields, check if 10 times or not